# JavaFX NumberAxis AutoRange Infinite Loop

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, linechart

I have a `LineChart` where the Y-Axis is set to auto range. Occasionally the JavaFx Thread hangs due to `NumberAxis.autoRange()` getting stuck in an infinite loop. New data generated by a worker thread and then added to the chart (on JFX thread) every few seconds. The infinite loop happens in this code (taken from `NumberAxis.autoRange()`):

```
for (double major = minRounded; major <= maxRounded; major += tickUnitRounded, count ++)  {
   double size = side.isVertical() ? measureTickMarkSize(major, getTickLabelRotation(), formatter).getHeight() :
                                        measureTickMarkSize(major, getTickLabelRotation(), formatter).getWidth();
   if (major == minRounded) { // first
      last = size/2;
   } else {
      maxReqTickGap = Math.max(maxReqTickGap, last + 6 + (size/2) );
   }
}
```

From debugging I've see that the `if (major == minRoundeed)` conditional is `true` every time. So, the `major` variable must not be getting updated.

I do not have a compiled version of the `NumberAxis` class with local variable debug info so I cannot see what the local variables are. Building the JavaFX Runtime classes seems like a lot of work but may be the next step.

I'm not able to reliably repro this issue and thus not able to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I have not seen any issues logged in the Oracle or OpenJDK bug databases.

JDK Version: 8u60

EDIT:

I reported a this bug with Oracle and currently waiting for them to accept it.

Comment: I can't see any way that `tickUnitRounded` can possibly be zero there (though really it's pretty bad practice to use `double` arithmetic in a loop like that). Is your chart animated? If so, does calling `setAnimated(false)` help? And I assume you are not breaking any threading rules. You probably need to come up with a [MCVE] to usefully post a bug report (or even get help here).

Comment: @James_D No threading rules are being broken AFAICT. JavaFX seems to fail fast if you try to access JFX components outside the JFX thread. I agree and have tried to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but the problem is I'm not sure how without local var info in the NumberAxis class. My next course of action at this point is to compile the JFX RT with debug info and get a repro.

Comment: @NwDx threading rules are not the issue here.

Comment: I guess before trying to build JavaFX, I would try to log from my own app the data that's being added to the chart. Since you're adding on the FX Application Thread, when that thread hangs, your logging will stop, so you should be able to figure out what values were in the chart when the problem occurred. That should be (?) enough to create MCVE. It's some work, but easier than building JFX. (OT threading discussion: most controls fail fast if you use the wrong thread, but not all. Trial and error suggests a `LineChart` fails fast only if it is not animated.)

Comment: The chart is animated so I can try turning that off. Just using the data values sent right before the hang occurs is not enough to create a MCVE (I tried before asking this question) because there are other variables in play (e.g. the chart size) but I will continue to try by logging more values. Making a copy of NumberAxis is not exactly straight forward since it references several default scoped methods in it's base class (e.g. scalePropertyImpl). NumberAxis is also a final class so no inheritance. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Found the problem. When `tickUnitRounded` is very small it will not change the value of `major` which results in the infinite loop. Working on a MCVE now but may take a while. Definitely a JDK bug due to floating point arithmetic. Good call @James_D.

Comment: Yeah... (fairly obviously) if `tickUnitRounded` is very small compared to `major`, rounding errors will mean that adding it to `major` results in no change. It seems like the preceding code should make that an impossibility, though, unless there's something really quirky with the size of the axis and the size of the labels. (But even then it seems it would require ~10^16 tick marks...). Still... don't use floating point arithmetic to control loops - we all learnt that in elementary school, I think :).

Comment: Well I made a little example that shows the counter parts of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

The meant loop will rely on double values. So if you try to take so small double values for minValue and maxValue, it will fail.

#### Bug or not?

To me it's not like a bug. You can ask yourself, if you really want to show such big fractions on your axis, or can you scale them better up? The user of your Application maybe even happier with reading 1.5 with the base on the axis label than 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000015 or 1.5E-33?

And there be more things in the whole Java API where this can happen too, because it's a simple number overflow.

#### A simple example

This will demonstrate, that if the values are too small, it will loop infinite.

```
import javafx.geometry.Side;


public class AutoRangeTester {

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AutoRangeTester art = new AutoRangeTester();
    art.autoRange(Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.MIN_VALUE + 0.000000000000000000000000000000001, 100, 50);
  }

  /**
   * Called to set the upper and lower bound and anything else that needs to be
   * auto-ranged
   *
   * @param minValue  The min data value that needs to be plotted on this axis
   * @param maxValue  The max data value that needs to be plotted on this axis
   * @param length    The length of the axis in display coordinates
   * @param labelSize The approximate average size a label takes along the axis
   *
   * @return The calculated range
   */
  public Object autoRange(double minValue, double maxValue, double length,
                          double labelSize) {
    final Side side = Side.LEFT;
    // check if we need to force zero into range
    if (true) {
      if (maxValue < 0) {
        maxValue = 0;
      } else if (minValue > 0) {
        minValue = 0;
      }
    }
    final double range = maxValue - minValue;
    // pad min and max by 2%, checking if the range is zero
    final double paddedRange = (range == 0) ? 2 : Math.abs(range) * 1.02;
    final double padding = (paddedRange - range) / 2;
    // if min and max are not zero then add padding to them
    double paddedMin = minValue - padding;
    double paddedMax = maxValue + padding;
    // check padding has not pushed min or max over zero line
    if ((paddedMin < 0 && minValue >= 0) || (paddedMin > 0 && minValue <= 0)) {
      // padding pushed min above or below zero so clamp to 0
      paddedMin = 0;
    }
    if ((paddedMax < 0 && maxValue >= 0) || (paddedMax > 0 && maxValue <= 0)) {
      // padding pushed min above or below zero so clamp to 0
      paddedMax = 0;
    }
    // calculate the number of tick-marks we can fit in the given length
    int numOfTickMarks = (int) Math.floor(length / labelSize);
    // can never have less than 2 tick marks one for each end
    numOfTickMarks = Math.max(numOfTickMarks, 2);
    // calculate tick unit for the number of ticks can have in the given data range
    double tickUnit = paddedRange / (double) numOfTickMarks;
    // search for the best tick unit that fits
    double tickUnitRounded = 0;
    double minRounded = 0;
    double maxRounded = 0;
    int count = 0;
    double reqLength = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    // loop till we find a set of ticks that fit length and result in a total of less than 20 tick marks
    while (reqLength > length || count > 20) {
      int exp = (int) Math.floor(Math.log10(tickUnit));
      final double mant = tickUnit / Math.pow(10, exp);
      double ratio = mant;
      if (mant > 5d) {
        exp++;
        ratio = 1;
      } else if (mant > 1d) {
        ratio = mant > 2.5 ? 5 : 2.5;
      }

      tickUnitRounded = ratio * Math.pow(10, exp);

      minRounded = Math.floor(paddedMin / tickUnitRounded) * tickUnitRounded;
      maxRounded = Math.ceil(paddedMax / tickUnitRounded) * tickUnitRounded;

      count = 0;
      for (double major = minRounded; major <= maxRounded; major
              += tickUnitRounded, count++) {
        System.out.println("minRounded: " + minRounded);
        System.out.println("maxRounded: " + maxRounded);
        System.out.println("major: " + major);
        System.out.println("tickUnitRounded: " + tickUnitRounded);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
      }

    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

#### UPDATE

The Bug-Report: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8136535
A fix is scheduled for version 9.

Comment: Thanks @NwDx for the idea to create a copy of NumberAxis. I ended up using reflection to get around the scoping issues (specifically to get access to ValueAxis.scale field). That was way easier than building JavaFX RT.

Comment: Ah, beat me to posting the MCVE. I believe it is a bug because the client of a chart should not have to sanitize (truncate) input values to a chart. A client should be able to use whatever random double data (in my case the result of calculations being performed on realtime sensor data). It's not that I need to show data at that precision but rather that's just what the data happens to be. Thanks again for the assistance.

Comment: @jenglert It seems to be a matter of taste. To me a client of a chart needs to ask himself: If I use a double value, what can happen with it? In special when it works near bounds of min and max values. I don't spend much time in finding a better approach of this method, but for sure, they should catch such situations better. So feel free to report it as a bug, may they decide to change it.